# How can I change the app url for unit testing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a function which requires the url to be able to work. I am trying to unit test it as its behaviour changes depending on the url query parameters.

MyServiceTest.php

```
function testMyTestFunction() {
    $service = new MyService();

    // Some how change the url for the app. This doesn't work
    config(['app.url' => 'http://test.test?myNewParam=5']);

    $service->test();
}
```

MyService.php

```
function test() {
    // Does not contain `myNewParam`
    $url = url()->full();

    // do some logic
}
```

I've also tried mocking the request as that's what the `url()` helper function references but I've had no luck in doing this successfully.

Comment: config var is a variable avalible for estMyTestFunction() function, if you no pass the param o the other function test(), you need read the url from config file o global variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `url()->full();` this returns the current request full URL, not the one set in the config. So when using this:

```
config(['app.url' => 'http://test.test?myNewParam=5']);
```

then you can get the value like this: `config('app.url')`.

If you want to get the param through the `url` helper then you will need to make a request to the controller route that uses your service, for example:

```
$this->get('/test?myNewParam=5')->assert...
```

but then that would not be a unit test. You should better move out the usage of your `url` helper function from within your service method and provide that as a dependency to the service. That way you can use one url for your production code and another for your test code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you are saying it's not easily possible to do this in a unit test?

Comment: It is if you use dependency injection. Because if your code depends on a Laravel own helper function than it is not really a unit test. You would want to extract those dependencies as much as possible. So don't use `url()` helper within your method in the service, but pass it as an argument either to the method or to the constructor of the service if you use it in more than one method.

Comment: Ok, good idea. I'll just pass in the url from the function that's calling this one. Thanks.